# Size content to viewport issue with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I was using Google's PageSpeed tool and came across an issue on my homepage that I'm not sure how to fix. The suggestion is to fix "Size content to viewport" but I've never run into this issue before using Twitter Bootstrap. Can someone please take a look at my site and see if there's something I'm missing?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">...</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">...</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried creating removing the "text-center" class from the div and that didn't seem to work.

PageSpeed: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=game-brain.com&tab=mobile

Website: http://game-brain.com/

Comment: Your structure isn't correct: `container / row`, not `row / container` which is causing the page to overflow which might be the problem since it creates a horizontal scrollbar. See [Grid-system](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have placed container inside row.kindly, place row inside container.

i.e.

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:30px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
      <h4>Stay current</h4>
      <p>Play smarter by staying up to date with the latest Clash of Clan strategies provided by our community and the Game Brain team.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
      <h4>Extensive testing</h4>
      <p>All of our guides go through extensive play testing to determine if the strategy is viable for the current meta game.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
      <h4>Contribute</h4>
      <p>Our team encourages the gaming community to help contribute to the site. Reach out to us and help other players.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Row-fluid does not exist in Bootstrap V3.

Comment: Ugh. This was such a silly mistake. Sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes looking at the problem. Thank you so much!